# Angular ui-router ui-sref-opts to update address bar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have path params of the form:

/mask/:username

and I have ui-sref and ui-sref-opts for the form:

```
<a ui-sref="mask" ui-sref-opts="{username: '@myusername'}">Mask</a>
```

But when this link is followed, no username parameter is passed, and no location bar (Html5 mode on) parameter is updated.

I want the address bar result of following to be

```
/mask/@myusername
```

Much thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Have you specified `username` in your route? Can you show your route?

Comment: Yes. URL: '/mask/:username' This works in the physical href='/mask/@myname' case

Comment: Btw what is `@myusername` ? is that the value? Try `ui-sref="mask({username: '@myusername'})"`

Comment: O snap, yes, thanks. Please put that in an answer and I will accept.

Comment: I have added as answer, thx!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my comment to an answer. I am not sure about ui-sref-opts But you could pass the parameters as an argument to the state in the [`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) itself, provided your  route has that param configured.

Try:-

```
 ui-sref="mask({username: '@myusername'})"
```